# How to Test ElasticSearch Logstash and Kibana

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have installed elasticsearch, logstash and kibana to my Debian server. The problem is Kibana is not showing any statistics or logs. I don't know what is wrong and how to debug this problem. When I test each of the components (elasticsearch, kibana and logstash) everything looks working properly.

## ElasticSearch Tests

- Checking elasticsearch-cluster status:

> curl 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health?v'

```
{"cluster_name":"elasticsearch","status":"yellow","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary_shards":71,"active_shards":71,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":71,"number_of_pending_tasks":0}
```

- Checking elasticsearch-node status:

> curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v'

```
host ip            heap.percent ram.percent load node.role master name    
ais  193.xx.yy.zz            6      10     0.05      d       *   Shathra
```

- Checking elasticsearch-index status:

> curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'

```
health status index              pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow open   countries            5   1        243          365    145.2kb        145.2kb 
yellow open   imports              5   1         26            7     49.6kb         49.6kb 
yellow open   categories           5   1          6            1     20.6kb         20.6kb 
yellow open   faculties            5   1         36            0     16.9kb         16.9kb 
yellow open   users                5   1       6602           29      1.8mb          1.8mb 
yellow open   cities               5   1        125            0     23.5kb         23.5kb 
yellow open   exam_languages       5   1        155            0     26.6kb         26.6kb 
yellow open   departments          5   1        167           70    166.4kb        166.4kb 
yellow open   examinations         5   1          4            0     14.1kb         14.1kb 
yellow open   certificates         5   1          1            0        3kb            3kb 
yellow open   .kibana              1   1          2            1       14kb           14kb 
yellow open   exam_centers         5   1          5            0     22.7kb         22.7kb
```

- Checking elasticsearch-service status:

> $ service elasticsearch status

```
[ ok ] elasticsearch is running.
```

ElasticSearch is also reacable from localhost:9200 in my browser and listing indexes correct.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/elasticsearch file =>**

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name es.xxx.yyy.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/elasticsearch/ssl/es_domain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/elasticsearch/ssl/es_domain.key;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/elasticsearch/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/elasticsearch/error.log debug;
  location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9200;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:9200 http://es.xxx.yyy.com/;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    auth_basic "Elasticsearch Authentication";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/elasticsearch/user.pwd;
  }
}

server{
  listen 80;
  server_name es.xxx.yyy.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

## Kibana Tests

> $ service kibana4 status

```
[ ok ] kibana is running.
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/kibana file =>**

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name kibana.xxx.yyy.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /opt/kibana/ssl/es_domain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /opt/kibana/ssl/es_domain.key;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/kibana/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/kibana/error.log debug;
  location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:5601 http://kibana.xxx.yyy.com/;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    auth_basic "Kibana Authentication";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;
  }
}

server{
  listen 80;
  server_name kibana.xxx.yyy.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Kibana is also reacable from localhost:5601 in my browser without any problem.

## Logstash Tests

> $ sudo /etc/init.d/logstash status

```
[ ok ] logstash is running.
```

**/etc/logstash/conf.d/01-ais-input.conf file =>**

```
input {
  file {
    type => "rails"
    path => "/srv/www/xxx.yyy.com/site/log/logstasher.log" 
    codec => json {
      charset => "UTF-8"
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
   host => 'localhost'
   port => 9200
  }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with these services and config files? Each of the components look working fine but I can not see anything in Kibana interface. How can I test my ELK stack?

Comment: Have you configured Kibana to load your elasticsearch indices?

Comment: How can I configure Kibana?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure index patterns in Kibana to see the elasticsearch data.

1. Open Kibana from your browser `http://localhost:5601`
2. Click on Settings
3. Type your existing index name and click Create. (Uncheck the option 'Index contains time-based events' unless your index is having logs or any time-stamp based data)

Doing this, you must be able to see all your elasticsearch documents.

[image]

Comment: The problem is, I can't see anything under "Discover", "Visualize" or "Dashboard" tab. I want to see that fancy statistics and maps.

Also, how can I index the logs? As I check my elasticsearch indexes - I can not see anything related with logs.

Comment: Did you tried my answer posted above? Once you add the indices into Kibana with the above procedure, you can configure the parameters in the Visualize screen to see the 'fancy' statistics

Comment: I know this is old answer but I am stuck at point 3. how and where to find existing index names? I assume i will be using kabana to create indexes? or there is any step before this where i need to create indexes?

Comment: Kibana is just for visualising. You need to create index via Elasticsearch. This is how you create index - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

Comment: In the Kibana version I am using the UI differed quite a bit and the index creation was found under `Management` > `Index Patterns` > `Create index pattern`.